# Нужная ли запятая перед "или"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение, или

> Проверь, что на карте достаточно денег(,) или используй другую карту.

Как мне кажется, в данном предложении нужна запятая перед "или", поскольку она закрывает сложноподчинённую часть в предложении. Верно?

Comment: Вроде да, нужна, закрывает сложноподчинённую часть.

Comment: Закрывает **придаточную** часть сложноподчинённого предложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, верно. Запятая нужна.
Она закрывает придаточное предложение, относящееся к первому глаголу.

Comment: Не нравится мне стилистика этого предложения) Проверь, что на карте достаточно денег. – Как я проверю-то? – Короче, давай другую карту или наличку. Лучше уж так: Проверь, что на карте достаточно денег; или используй другую карту.

Comment: @Sharon  Вы пишете: "Лучше уж так: Проверь, что на карте достаточно денег; или используй другую карту".  Ничего не изменилось... //  Нормально всё со стилистикой. Человек приложил карту, но платёж не прошёл. Он уверяет, что деньги на карте есть. А другой ему говорит то, что, собственно, мы и разбираем.

Comment: Ага, говорит. Но здесь нельзя назвать эти действия однородными: проверь эту,  давай другую. Между ними хорошая ПАУЗА, пока идет разборка.  Вот ее надо обозначить точкой с запятой.  Я так слышу)

Comment: @Sharon Слышимость – дело субъективное. // Мы говорим о письменном воспроизведении разговора. Да, можно поставить даже точку, но по большому счёту и запятой достаточно. Я так слышу. В беглой речи пауза вообще минимальна.

Comment: Я же только свое мнение высказала. Не нравится мне эта фраза в принципе. С картой может быть что угодно, может, ее заблокировали или еще что. Проверить деньги невозможно. Но все, как попугаи, ее повторяют.

Comment: @Sharon *"Как я проверю-то?"* / *"Проверить деньги невозможно"*  –  Как так?!  Заходим в приложение карты или в терминал банкомата и проверяем. Дело одной минуты.

Comment: Или двух минут. А Интернет с собой?  Проверили, деньги есть, а карта все равно не проходит. Народ на вас поглядывает с неудовольствием. Здесь уже многоточие надо ставить)  Логики в этом сообщении никакой.

Comment: @Sharon  :)))) Это уже другие проблемы, обращайтесь к провайдеру, банку и "прочей технике" – к русскому языку это уже не относится.

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста. Просто я "слышу"  неоднородность, только и всего.

Comment: @Sharon Да, скорее всего, неоднородность (хотя, как вы недавно говорили о повелит. наклонении и односоставных предложениях, их можно приравнять с однородными), но наличие придаточного нивелирует этот "затык", запятые (или прочие знаки) наложились друг на друга, слились.

Comment: Я все равно чувствую остановку голоса, слова совершенно не стыкуются друг с другом.  // В реальности же все происходит так. Платеж не прошел, попробуйте еще раз. Нет, не проходит. Тогда используйте другую карту или оплатите покупку наличными. // А эта фраза ни о чем.  // Но вы все все равно извините, что отвлекаю. До новых приятных встреч)

Comment: @Sharon Да нет, очень хорошо, что "отвлекаете" – это же способствует копанию. Ваше мнение и чувствование мне всегда интересно. Спасибо!